# Using Log DNA for Cloud Foundry Apps in IBM Cloud

Tags: logging, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

Can we use Log DNA for Cloud Foundry apps in IBM Cloud? I have looked at the Log DNA documentation in IBM Cloud and did not find any reference to using it with Cloud Foundry apps.

Answer (score 0):

it is very easy to send CloudFoundry logs from apps like nodeJS to LogDNA.

1. set up an "IBM Cloud Log Analysis with LogDNA" Instance in your region
2. configure sources in your region

now the logs should appear after a few minutes in your LogDNA instance.

Answer (score -1):

It should be possible to send Cloud Foundry logs to LogDNA. In general, Cloud Foundry logs can be passed to different log stores. LogDNA itself provides this [firehose to LogDNA code](https://github.com/logdna/logdna-cloudfoundry). That code is based on the [Cloud Foundry repo to send logs to syslog](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog).